# How to send line break using curl?

Tags: curl, confluence

I'm trying to create confluence page for each file present in one of the directory. I'm using the below curl command to achieve it

```
$ cat test.txt
foo
bar

curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -u username:password  -d  '{ "ancestors": [ { "id": "65601" } ], "body": { "storage": { "value": "'"$(cat test.txt)"'", "representation": "storage" } }, "space": { "key": "TEST" }, "status": "current", "title": "Page1", "type": "page" }' 'http://localhost:8090/rest/api/content';
```

This is how it looks when seen in debug mode

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -u username:password  -d  '{ "ancestors": [ { "id": "65601" } ], "body": { "storage": { "value": "foo
bar", "representation": "storage" } }, "space": { "key": "TEST" }, "status": "current", "title": "Page1", "type": "page" }' 'http://localhost:8090/rest/api/content';
```

I have even tested with this option --data-binary, it didn't work.

I want the file (test.txt) content to be reflected as-is in the confluence page i.e it should retain new line as-is.

It did not work even after putting \n like the below

```
"storage": { "value": "foo\nbar" }
```

Any suggestion how to achieve this using curl?

Answer (score 1):

`--data-binary` *will* preserve and pass on all white space characters, including newlines while the ordinary `-d/--data` option will not. It will not introduce any of them by itself though so you need to make sure your data includes them.

Also, please avoid `-X POST` with `-d` as it's unnecessary at best, causing problems at worst.

### verify

If you want to verify that your POST is exactly the way you want it to be, I would recommend adding `--trace-ascii dump.txt` to your command line and then check that `dump.txt` file after the fact and verify that the body was sent exactly the way you wanted it to.

Comment: It's a POST method and body is a must for the particular API call. Any idea how to get it working.

Comment: My answer is.. eh, the answer!